# How to insert a Jtable data into oracle 11g database

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

[These are the exceptions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXhud.png)we have created a jtable,the data is added to the table by add button.And it is sent to databse through a submit button.But exceptions are generated when the submit button is clicked.Can anyone tell me where the code went wrong??

```
btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    try {

        int count = table.getRowCount();
                        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","scott", "tiger");
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("Insert into students(ROLL_NO,NAME,MID1,MID2,Marksinwords) values (?,?,?,?,?)");

        for(int row = 0; row<count; row++)
        {
             String roll = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 0);
             String name = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 1);


                             String MARKS1 = (String)tableModel.getValueAt(row, 2);
            String MARKS2 = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 3);

             String marksinwords = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 4);

             pst.setString(1, roll);
              pst.executeUpdate(roll);
                 pst.setString(2, name);
              pst.executeUpdate(name);
             pst.setString(3,MARKS1 );
              pst.executeUpdate(MARKS1);
             pst.setString(4,MARKS2 );
              pst.executeUpdate(MARKS2);

                 pst.setString(5, marksinwords);

               pst.executeUpdate(marksinwords);
                pst.addBatch();
        }
        pst.executeBatch();
        conn.commit();

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                Logger.getLogger(FacultyTableSubmit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

    }

});
```

Comment: Which exception ?

Comment: I have added the screenshot

Comment: Please never post an exception as a screenshot, always present the text. If you are lucky SO will automatically suggest you a post where you can find the solution if it is able to recognize an exception that already can be found in a prior post. Besides that your exception is not shown completely, it was cut off

Comment: Sure.Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence with the PreparedStatement looks a bit strange to me and you do not need to provide a value when updating it and you do two things, you add it to the db and then again to a batch.

Try it like this:

```
    for(int row = 0; row<count; row++)
    {
        String roll = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 0);
        String name = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 1);
        String MARKS1 = (String)tableModel.getValueAt(row, 2);
        String MARKS2 = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 3);
        String marksinwords = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 4);

        pst.setString(1, roll);;
        pst.setString(2, name);
        pst.setString(3,MARKS1 );
        pst.setString(4,MARKS2 );
        pst.setString(5, marksinwords);
        pst.addBatch();
    }
    pst.executeBatch();
    conn.commit();
```

Comment: I've changed the code.Again the same exceptions @Fredy Fisher